# How to check SOUNDEX in php when php SOUNDEX outputs only 3 digits

Tags: soundex, php

I am trying to do a comparison between company names using SOUNDEX, but the php call for soundex only outputs 3 digits so the comparisons aren't quite accurate.  Is there a way to get a better soundex output so that the results are more accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [metaphone](http://us.php.net/metaphone) instead

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are SOUNDEXing against, it might be cheaper to do run [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)
at the database level:

```
$result = $db->query("
    SELECT
        company.id,
        company.name,
        SOUNDEX(company.name) AS soundex
    FROM
        company
    WHERE
        company.name SOUNDS LIKE '$companyName'
");
```

Comment: should I create within the mysql database itself what the soundex index is ahead of time?

Comment: In my opinion, the benefits of doing so (marginal performance increase) do not outweigh the pain/expense (keeping the column in sync). I set up a table with 5000 unique names, indexed name column, and ran SOUNDEX on all. Results: 1.8ms average vs 1.5ms for just retrieving the data without SOUNDEX